# Maximal height to a div that is children of 100% min-height body

Tags: html, css

At first I want to apologize for putting my code straight into the question, but I see no point putting a fiddle of that as the jsfiddle seems not to support my idea at all.

I have a document's scaffold like

```
<body>
    <div id = "top" class = "top">
        <div class = "container-pageblock">
            <div class = "block-content">
                <div class = "some-element">rolololo</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class = "footer-pageblock">
            <div class = "block-content">foter</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

with css rules that go

```
html
{
    height: 100%;
}
body
{
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%
}
.top
{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative;
}
[class $= "-pageblock"]
{
    width: 100%;
}
[class $= "-pageblock"] .block-content
{
    width: 1080px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.top, [class $= "-pageblock"]
{
    min-width: 1080px;
}

.container-pageblock
{
    background-color: #afa;
}
.footer-pageblock
{
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    background: #dde;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.some-element
{
    height: 500px;
}
```

My goal is to have the footer stuck to the bottom of the browser (with some blank space between `.container-pageblock` and `.footer-pageblock` when the content is too little) and as the content grows, the footer to be at the bottom of the *document*. Which basically means that I need the footer to be **at most** (not higher than) at the bottom of the browser window.

The problem seems to be that the `div.top`'s `min-height: 100%` does not make its height as the `body` height. The effect is that when the browser height is (much) more than the contents' height, the `.footer-pageblock`'s bottom is at the bottom of the `.content-pageblock` instead of the bottom of the browser.

Firebug indicates that `body`'s height does have at least 100%.

I can't make it work for Firefox and IEs up to 9). However the code seems to work in latest Chrome and IE 10.

What is more, I really want to have this html preserved (that is keep the `.footer-pageblock` inside `.top`)

**EDIT**

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994686/min-height-100-doesnt-work-on-inner-div) and its answer, I just needed to specify `height: 100%` to `body`. Contrary to what I expected, this does not make `.top`'s height to the browser's height. Solved.

Comment: unfortunately when using height 100%, the parent's height can't be set with min-height - it needs an actual height setting too

Comment: Does the footer have a fixed height?

Comment: Does this thing work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994686/, (setting height and min-height on both body and html).

Comment: @TrondHatlen, I saw that answer before but did not even try it as I expected that giving `height: 100%` to body would make it unable to have more content than the browser height. However, this actually works! Thank you

Comment: Nice, It's kind of frustrating with all these different browser quirks that you need to know to give the right special treatment to the right browser, especially when you're so close as you were.

Comment: Indeed, it is. Dreaming of some magical solution to css issues like jQuery is to JS